# Visual Studio access Pointer variable

Tags: variables, pointers

I have some serious trouble with Visual Studio, its driving me insane...

When a Class makes a new instance of another Class, I usually pass `"this"` to its constructor, and have an easy access to the parent Class.

```
parentPointer->myVariable
```

But with visual studio it just won't work.
I have the pointer, and i can access 8 million methods/variables, but just not my own public variables.

With the debugger i can actually see the variables and their values...

the structure looks like this:

```
parentPointer->MyClass::myVariable
```

So I can actually find the variables with that (weird) syntax. But then I get this error:

> qualified name is not a member of class "CWnd" or its base class.

So I wasted one more hour on a super simple task with that Visual Studio...
(If it helps, its a MFC Application)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Greetings

UPDATE

---

Ok finally got it...
I simply modified the new standard constructor:

```
newClass::newClass(CWnd* pParent, parentClass* parentPointer);
```

With the additional Parameter 'parentPointer' i can now use:

```
parentPointer->myVariable ! :)
```

I somehow thought it should automatically work with pParent...
(Its still pretty strange that with  debugger I had all values ect. accessible in the pParent...)

PS: Thanks for making my Thread more readable, i still haven't figured out how to format it properly xD

Comment: If you have found an answer to your own question, please don't edit your question but post an actual answer with in. You can then accept your own answer.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but apparently I can't answer my own question within 8 hours... :P